# Calculated field only calculates one row instead of all rows in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, calculated-field

I have calculated field that divides two fields from a table, but when the query is running, the query only calculates the first row of the calculated field and not all rows.

I am using a simple calculation in my calculated field, so I am not sure why this is happening.

My entire expression:

```
SELECT LlamadoDeCapital.ID, LlamadoDeCapital.TotalCapitalCommitted, LlamadoDeCapital.CapitalCallRequestDate, LlamadoDeCapital.CapitalCallDate, LlamadoDeCapital.CurrentCapitalCall, DSum("CurrentCapitalCall","LlamadoDeCapital","CapitalCallDate <=" & CLng([CapitalCallDate])) AS TotalCapitalCalls, [CurrentCapitalCall]/[TotalCapitalCommitted] AS [%CurrentCuotaPaid]
FROM LlamadoDeCapital;
```

Sample that only calculates one cell:

```
[CurrentCapitalCall]/[TotalCapitalCommitted] AS [%CurrentCuotaPaid]
```

I'm sure I am probably missing something simple. I appreciate any help or suggestions you can offer.

Comment: A field (there are no cells in Access) always contains a value or Null. So if you see "empty" fields, you have Null values.

Comment: can you post sample data?

Comment: For sample data: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: Gustav was right. There was only data in the first field. Is there a way I can make function only refer to that one field, the TotalCapitalCommitted field, and not the entire column that is lacking data? This field changes periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Gustav was right. There was only data in the first field. Is there a way I can make function only refer to that one field, the TotalCapitalCommitted field, and not the entire column that is lacking data? This field changes periodically.